# Why does my file pointer in C become null when the second fgets is executed?

Tags: c, file-io, fgets

I want to read a file, the first two lines. the program is :

```
    int main(void)
    {
      FILE *fp;
      char buf[1024];
      char value[128];
      long mem[2];
      char *pos;

      if (!(fp = fopen("example.txt", "r"))) {
        printf("CANNOT open example.txt\n");  
        return -2;
      }


      for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        fgets(buf, 1024, fp);
        pos = strstr(buf, ":");
        if (!pos) {
            printf("MEMINFO wrong format\n");
            return -1;
        }

        strncpy(value, pos + 1, 128);
        mem[i] = atol(value);

        memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
        memset(value, 0, sizeof(buf));
      }

}
```

and example.txt is like :

```
MemTotal:        3541412 kB
MemFree:          123500 kB
Buffers:           11372 kB
Cached:          2582072 kB
SwapCached:         1520 kB
Active:          1832328 kB
Inactive:        1493348 kB
Active(anon):    1608692 kB
Inactive(anon):  1269620 kB
Active(file):     223636 kB
```

It generates a segfault error when the second fgets is reached. Using gdb, I found the file pointer fp becomes 0 in the second fgets. What is the problem? Can fgets be used like this?

Comment: post the contents of `example.txt`

Comment: Always check for the fgets error:: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c37dh6kf(v=vs.71).aspx
you can use "strchr" if searching for a char:: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b34ccac3(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check that `fgets()` succeeds, before relying on the results.

Also, why are you doing the `memset()` calls, both `buf` and `value` should be overwritten when all goes well anyway. It causes a bug:

```
 memset(value, 0, sizeof(buf));
```

Wrong buffer size.

Comment: OMG. I copy the first memset and forget to change the parameter. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of main, you need to call fclose() to close fp.
The memset() calls are not needed. fgets() set '\0' at the end of buf.